# AcceptChanges() throws System.NullReferenceException in DataGridView when using space bar for changing CheckBox

Tags: c#, exception, datagridview, datatable, .net-4.0

In my `DataGridView` I use a DataView to filter the DataTable. The `CheckBox` value is used in the filter.

When the CheckBox is unchecked, the row should disappear. To run that immediately, I use `AcceptChanges()` in an `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event. (Otherwise the row stays displayed, until another row is selected).

> This works when I unselect the checkbox with the mouse. **Using the space bar** a **NullReferenceException** exception is thrown.

**Here is some sample code:**

(Full working. Needs only Form1 with a blank DataGridView1. Changing the CheckBox with space bar throws the exception)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable table;
        DataView view; 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Init();
        }

        // Building the table and view
        private void Init()
        {
            table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("check", typeof(bool));

            table.Rows.Add(true);
            table.Rows.Add(true);
            table.Rows.Add(true);

            view = new DataView(table);
            view.RowFilter = "check = true";

            dataGridView1.DataSource = view;
        }

        // CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged Event
        private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty == true && dataGridView1.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
            {
                dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);

                // AcceptChanges to update the view
                // works with mouse click, throws NullReferenceException when spacebar is used
                table.AcceptChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way make it working with the space bar also?

**Edit**
The exception is thrown anywhere in the .net runtime and not directly by AcceptChanges()

```
System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
     bei System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.NotifyMASSClient(Point position)
     bei System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e, Int32 rowIndex)
     bei System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
     bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)
     bei System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)
     bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)
     bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
     bei System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
     bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
     bei System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
     bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
     bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
     bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
     bei Sample.Program.Main() in C:\Projects\TFS\Sample\Sample\Program.cs:Zeile 21.
```

Comment: Can you post the full Stack Track of the exception?  I'm curious as to exactly what in the stack is throwing it.

Comment: you can find a workaround here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780347/nullreferenceexception-in-notifymassclient-after-checking-unchecking-a-checkbox-in-datagridview-with-spacebar

Comment: @tezzo Works, thanks!!! I would accept this as answer!

Comment: answer added: please check my code; if it is different from the one you used, feel free to correct it.

Comment: @tezzo, welcome :) ... finally I found out how to write your answer with fewer code and added it as a further answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Invoke this way makes for me the code easier to read, because there is no explicit delegate declaration needed.

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty == true && dataGridView1.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
    {
        // use BeginInvoke with (MethodInvoker) to run the code after the event is finished
        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            table.AcceptChanges();
        });
    }
}
```

Works same like tezzos answer.

Answer (score 0):

As reported on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780347/nullreferenceexception-in-notifymassclient-after-checking-unchecking-a-checkbox-in-datagridview-with-spacebar) a potential workaround is to delay `CommitEdit` until `CellDirtyStateChanged` event handler completes.

```
public delegate void InvokeDelegate();

public void MyDelegate()
{
    dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    table.AcceptChanges();
}

//CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged Event
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty == true && dataGridView1.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(MyDelegate));
    }
}
```