# Invoke and Delegates in events - Why does the actions happen in this (unexpected) order?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, invoke, begininvoke

I had a [problem with component events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590324/acceptchanges-throws-exception-when-checkbox-is-changed-with-space-bar) which could be solved by using a `delegate`.

I haven't worked with delegates before, so I tested a little bit and found this strange behaviour:

> When using delegates the actions happen in a for me completely unexpected order.

**First sample:**

```
string Tracker = "";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Tracker = "A";

    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        Tracker += "B";
    });

    Tracker += "C";
}
```

After this `Tracker` contains `ACB`. Don't know how it works, but it seems to work as described.

---

**Second sample:**

```
string Tracker = "";

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Tracker = "A";
    MessageBox.Show(Tracker);

    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        Tracker += "B";
        MessageBox.Show(Tracker);
    });

    Tracker += "C";
    MessageBox.Show(Tracker);
}
```

After this `Tracker` also contains `ACB`, but the message boxes are shown in this order:

[image]
[image]
[image]

... and not `A` `AC` `ACB` as I would expect.

What is the explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sample 1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    Tracker = "A";

    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        Tracker += "B";
    });

   Tracker += "C";
}
```

First tracker is assigned,
next you push a delegate asynchronously on the GUI queue, so it is not happening until it gets a chance.
So next Tracker becomes AC.
Then the GUI thread comes free and hence you get ACB.
sample 2:

```
string Tracker = "";

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Tracker = "A";
    MessageBox.Show(Tracker);

    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        Tracker += "B";
        MessageBox.Show(Tracker);
    });

    Tracker += "C";
    MessageBox.Show(Tracker);
}
```

Still the same thing happens:
First the messagebox will appear for A, I think this is logical.
Next the delegate is pushed on the queue of the GUI thread
then Tracker becomes AC, and the messagebox is schedulled to run on the GUI thread and it is schedulled to show AC. But, because something else is schedulled on the GUI thread, that other thing is going to come first.
So first the delegate is going to execute, and then the AC is going to show.

If my explanation is still unclear at some point, post a comment, and tell me which part needs more elaboration.
But the bottom line is that actions are pushed to the GUI thread, and are executed by the GUI thread in the order as they appear to the GUI thread.

Answer (score 4):

This requires understanding how the dispatcher loop of a UI thread works.  When you use BeginInvoke(), you post a message to that loop that tells it to go look at the invoke queue.  That message is processed only *after* your code stops running and the Click event handler returns.  So what follows is that the `Tracker += "B";` statement will execute later, after your Click event handler stops running.

The MessageBox class also uses a dispatcher loop, but it is its own and not associated with the dispatcher loop of your program.  Which allows it to be *modal*.  So your Click method stalls on the last MessageBox.Show() call, its dispatcher loop starts dispatching messages and that triggers the invoked method.  Another MessageBox.Show() call, you see it first.  The dispatcher of the 2nd call is stuck until the dialog is closed.

This is a kind of re-entrancy that can cause very hard to diagnose bugs.  It makes the Application.DoEvents() method so dangerous.  Reasoning through the order in which code runs becomes very difficult.  MessageBox.Show() is in fact the equivalent of DoEvents().  But not quite as nasty, it acting like a dialog and disabling all other windows minimizes the number of mishaps.  It eliminates the odds that user-triggered events run in an unexpected order.  But doesn't eliminate them completely, it can't stop code.

---

FWIW, using BeginInvoke() like this can be *very* useful.  It can solve a number of problems caused by balky classes that generate events but don't respond well when you do "too much" inside the event handler.  The TreeView class is notable as a very temperamental class like that.  By using BeginInvoke(), you can be sure that the code runs *after* the code inside the balky class completed.